# unknown column in field list, column is really there

Tags: mysql, sql

I am getting an unknown column in field list error in a MySQL database select query, even though the column is actually there.  I even checked the spelling by right clicking on the MySQL command line client and using the Find... tool to search for the correct spelling, which turned up matches both in the column list resulting from describe table and in the column name in the select query.  How can I fix this?

Here is a screen capture of the MySQL command line client showing the error repeating even though I tested both the correct spelling UMLSCUI and an incorrect spelling UMLSCU1:

[image]

Here is a screen shot of the definition of the table:

[image]

Comment: What makes you think `umlscui` is a column in the table?  It appears to be a value for `atn`.  Please show the columns in `rxnsat`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to check the name of column `atn` if it contains spaces in your database.

if there is space before or after that column name than it will be unknown column.

EDIT:

how check spaces ?

Put your cursor in the column name to edit and move cursor to right and see if there is spaces or it stops at the end of column same thing to the left.

EDIT2:

you should do it like that

```
  select * from rxnsat
  where ATN = 'RXN_STRENGTH' or ATN = 'UMLSCUI'; --//as UMLSCUI is a value in atn column
```

Comment: I just added a screen shot of the table definition.  The field name does not seem to have spaces.  How can I tell for sure?

Comment: there is nothing wrong only if you have space in column name.

Comment: Thank you. I just wasn't seeing the problem clearly yesterday.  The second where argument is for a different field's CUI value.  But your suggestion helped me see where to look.

Answer (score 1):

Based off your sample query in your screenshot, it would appear as though you may be misunderstanding your table. I would suggest that you double-check your table and ensure that what you think is there, is actually there. There is not a column listed as `umlscui` in your table definition.

Comment: +1 and thank you for pointing in the right direction.  GordonLinoff gave the answer a few minutes earlier in a comment above.

Comment: No problem.  Suffering from a minor error has surely led many programmers down the wrong path many times.  This will be one of those that you should add to your common errors to check file.